# SQLite - Select records from a table with a date column and group by month

Tags: sqlite

I Have a table with a date column witch dates are saved as long values and I want to group records by month (But not Gregorian months!) and sum another column values.

I first created a temp table with two date columns(_from and _to) witch _from is first millis of a month and _to is last millis of that month.

then I made a selection like this:

```
 SELECT SUM(MY_TABLE.amount), TEMP_TABLE._from
 FROM MY_TABLE, TEMP_TABLE
 WHERE TEMP_TABLE._from <= MY_TABLE.date AND TEMP_TABLE._to >= MY_TABLE.date
 GROUP BY TEMP_TABLE._from;
```

MY_TABLE:
   **amount**:  the column I want to sum values for each month.
   **date:** date of each record.

But for 10K records it takes about 2 seconds to return result table, and it's too slow in my use case. I need a better solution.

Comment: Do you have any indexes?

Comment: What do you mean by index? MY_TABLE has id column as primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an index on the `_from` column, the database must write all `_from` values into a temporary table to be able to group them.
Without an index on the `date` column, it is not possible to look up values without scanning through the entire table.
You should have at least these [indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html):

```
CREATE INDEX Temp_Table_from ON Temp_Table(_from);
CREATE INDEX My_Table_date ON My_Table(date);
```

For this particular query, you can improve the performance even a little bit more by using [covering indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx):

```
CREATE INDEX Temp_Table_from_to ON Temp_Table(_from, _to);
CREATE INDEX My_Table_date_amount ON My_Table(date, amount);
```

---

Use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to check which indexes are actually used by a query.

Comment: I can also  create a unique index for temp_table._from to improve performance, right?

Comment: It does not matter whether an index is unique, or whether it is created implicitly for a constraint.